# How to show apache2 start page after install WordPress is successful?

Tags: wordpress, apache2, show

I'm a newbie.

I installed LAMP stack successfully! When I access `localhost`, apache2 start page is displayed:

[image: Apache default page]

And then, I installed WordPress on LAMP stack successfully! I access localhost/blog, it's works!

[image]

Here is my configuration Apache2 and wordpress in /etc/apache2/sites-available/wordpress.conf:

```
Alias /blog /usr/share/wordpress
<Directory /usr/share/wordpress>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride Limit Options FileInfo
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
<Directory /usr/share/wordpress/wp-content>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Here is my 000-default.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>  
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost     
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html  
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log    
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined 
</VirtualHost>
```

Here is my database on MySQL:

```
<?php
define('DB_NAME', 'wordpress');
define('DB_USER', 'wordpressuser');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'Wordpress@1111');
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_COLLATE', 'utf8_general_ci');
define('WP_CONTENT_DIR', '/usr/share/wordpress/wp-content');
?>
```

I checked apache2 status again, it's still running:
[image]
But when I access localhost again, it can not show apache2 start page.
[image]
So, how can I show apache2 start page in `http://localhost/` again?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Will you please post your full wordpress.conf file as well as the 000-default.conf?

Comment: Hi @Katie,
Here is my wp-config.conf in /etc/wordpress:
`<?php
define('DB_NAME', 'wordpress');
define('DB_USER', 'wordpressuser');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'Wordpress@1111');
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_COLLATE', 'utf8_general_ci');
define('WP_CONTENT_DIR', '/usr/share/wordpress/wp-content');
define('WP_ALLOW_REPAIR', true);
?>`
Thank u so much for suppot!

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear, I meant the Apache configuration files: /etc/apache/sites-available files, both the one for your site and the 000-default one, I think you are running into an apache configuration issue

Comment: My wordpress.conf:
`Alias /blog /usr/share/wordpress
<Directory /usr/share/wordpress>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride Limit Options FileInfo
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
<Directory /usr/share/wordpress/wp-content>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>`
And here is my 000-default.conf:
`<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
 DocumentRoot /var/www/html
 ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
 CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>`

Comment: Hi @Katie , 
I think my database and server are OK. But i was wrong when configure file.
I don't know how to show Apache2 Ubuntu Default Page on my localhost.
I don't know where i was wrong. Please help me! :(

Comment: Hi @Michael, Bummer, I don't see why your default configuration wouldn't still work.  You could look into Virtual Hosts, https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-18-04  - more work, but separates out web configurations allowing the default to its job